# Handling input and output in automation of a functionality?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, bdd

Let's say that you have to test a new way of getting a sum of two numbers from software and you have to test that functionality and do BDD automation.
From below two what would be a better approach for automation (Also why)?

1) Using fixed input and expecting the same output. Ex: Input -> 3,5 Output -> 8

OR

2) Using random two number on every run and validating it against the conventional sum.

Answer (score 1):

The first.

BDD isn't really about testing; it's about using examples to illustrate desired behaviour. The examples we use are "exemplars"; specifically picked for that illustration.

In your case, the sum is a pretty trivial problem. When we're dealing with more complex business behaviour though, we'll ask, "Can you give me an example?" The conversation that follows is the most important part of BDD. From that, we get realistic examples of the kind of inputs we'll be handling, and not just the expected output but also the value of that output, and who it's valuable to.

Once we automate the scenarios, they provide tests as a nice by-product, but that's not all they do. They're also living documentation. Business people can read them to see what a system does, and team members can use them to get a feel for the capabilities already in place.

That's a lot harder if the scenarios are generic ("a random number" and "another random number" and "a result") rather than specific ("2" and "3" and "5").

Answer (score 0):

I like Lunivore's answer, it's interesting. Expect this thread to be banned from SO in 15 mins! :)

You haven't explained the *business value* in what you're doing. Trivially, using a random input is more complex than a fixed input, so more things could go wrong, making it worse. But maybe you WANT to test random inputs? Maybe there is some kind of value, but you haven't given enough information?

I'd say that you're putting the cart before the horse, and looking at it from a junior TDD programmer's perspective, not a senior BDD developer's perspective. The "business value" is something that is often above someone's particular paygrade. But that's where BDD starts from, it's not where it end's up.

I'd ask you, "What is the perceived value in being able to sum these numbers? Are you a crazy person? Why are you talking to a consultant about this?"